# How to call Facebook Api to extract data and prefil a Form

Tags: angularjs, facebook

I am doing a registration form where I call the facebook API get some data and fill my form with the data needed. I am doing smth like this in my controller:

```
$scope.fbRegister = function () {

            facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function (success) {

                if (!cordova) {
                    //this is for browser only
                    facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit(FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
                }
                alert(JSON.stringify(success, null, 3));
                if (success.status === 'connected') {
                    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your app, and response.authResponse supplies
                    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed request, and the time the access token
                    // and signed request each expire

                    facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/?fields=id,first_name,last_name,link,gender,email,birthday", ["public_profile", "email", "user_birthday"],
                        function(result) {
                            alert("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                            alert(result.first_name);


        $scope.formData = {
            name: result.first_name,
            password: "",
            confirmPassword: "",
            email: '',
        };
        })
        }
```

However I don't get the prefiled data in   `name: result.first_name,`.
I make an alert for that and I get the data but I cant get it fill the form.

Thank you

Comment: use console.log for debugging, not alert. console.log(result), for example.

Comment: Well I get the data here:    `alert("Result: " + JSON.stringify(result));
 alert(result.first_name);`
But here  ` name: result.first_name,`  I dont get anything

Comment: as i said, don´t use alert for debugging. that´s a very bad way to debug.

Comment: Because I debug on the device I use alert... But when I use console, the result is the same

Comment: and what result is that exactly? you did not show us the result of console.log(result). and you really need to figure out how to debug on a mobile device. if it´s android, it´s very easy. as i said, alert is the worst way to debug.

Comment: Its iphone. On the alert I get correct name but the field is not being updated

Comment: Do an `alert(JSON.stringify($scope.formData))` after you populated the data into the object – if that shows the expected result, then your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: That shows the expected result. But when I run the program my form is still empty eventhough I get the expected result when alerting their values